# Prove the inequality $a^{2 b}+b^{2 a}+\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2 \leq 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, monotone-functions

> > $a,b \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $a+b=2$. Prove that $$a^{2 b}+b^{2 a}+\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2 \leq 2$$

My effort:
Let $$E=a^{2 b}+b^{2 a}+\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2 $$
When $a=b=1$, Equality occurs.

Let $a \ne b, \: a>b$ ,so we can take $a=1+c, b=1-c$, where $0<c < 1$
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \Rightarrow f(c)=E=(1+c)^{2(1-c)}+(1-c)^{2(1+c)}+c^2
\end{gathered}
$$
Now $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is a monotone increasing function in $(0,e)$. Since both $1-c, 1+c$ are less than $e$, we have:
$$\begin{aligned}
  & 1-c<1+c \\
  \Rightarrow & f(1-c)<f(1+c) \\
  \Rightarrow & (1-c)^{\frac{1}{1-c}}<(1+c)^{\frac{1}{1+c}} \\
  \Rightarrow & (1-c)^{1+c}<(1+c)^{(1-c)} \\
  \Rightarrow & (1-c)^{2(1+c)}<(1+c)^{2(1-c)} \\
  \Rightarrow & E<2(1+c)^{2(1-c)}+c^2
 \end{aligned}$$

I am stuck here:

Comment: Interesting. Why did two users ask the same question within such a short period of time.

Answer (score -1):

$$a=1-t\ , \ b=1+t\ \ \ \ (0 \le t \le 1)$$

$$  f(t)=(1-t)^{2(1+t)}+(1+t)^{2(1-t)}+t^2$$

$$ (1-t)^{2(1+t)}=(1-t)^2((1-t)^t)^2 \le (1-t)^{2}(1-t^2)^2$$

$$((1+t)^{(1-t)})^2\le (1+t(1-t))^2$$

$$f(t)\le (1-t)^{2}(1-t^2)^2+ (1+t(1-t))^2+t^2 \le2-t^2(1+t)(1-t)^3\le 2$$